# Cannot get minimum value from a table using a vlookup from a different worksheet in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two worksheets. In Worksheet 1, I have a table like the following

```
ID|PRICE|SELLER

01|12,00|A

01|11,00|B

01|15,00|C

02|12,00|A

02|14,00|B
```

If I run the following inside the worksheet 1 in a random cell

=INDEX(B2:B4;MATCH(AGGREGATE(15;7;B2:B4/(B2:B4<>0);1);B2:B4;0))

I get PRICE 11,00 so far is correct.

Now I want to get that based on my ID from worksheet 2 and populate it like the following

```
ID|MIN PRICE|SELLER

01|11,00    |B

02|12,00    |A
```

How can I run a vlookup together with the first formula? from worksheet 2

Answer (score 3):

To get the Minimum price, you can use `MINIFS()`, then a multi-criteria `index/match` for the Seller.  (Of course, adjust ranges as necessary)

In `B9`:

```
=MINIFS($B$2:$B$6;$A$2:$A$6;A9)
```

then enter this one in `C9` as an array formula (use <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>)

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$6;MATCH(A9&B9;$A$2:$A$6&$B$2:$B$6;0))
```

[image]

Edit: Without `MINIFS()`, you can use `=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$6=A9;$B$2:$B$6))` as an array formula.

Comment: I have excel 2010 so I think minif is not supported

Comment: @Nikos - Does this work (enter as an Array Formula too): `=MIN(IF($A$2:$A$6=A9;$B$2:$B$6))`? (Put in `B9`)

Comment: I run this from worksheet 2 So I have =MIN(IF(Table1[ID]=[@ID];Table1[PRICE])) but I get #Value error

Comment: @Nikos - Hm, I think you have the IF statement comparison backwards. `=MIN(IF([@ID]=Table1[ID];Table1[PRICE]))`?  Again, make sure you enter as an array formula with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`, and not just `ENTER`.